# Emulate GPIO activity

Tags: gpio

I'm working on a project using GPIOs. I struggle to write some automated testing code.

I would like to emulate activity on `/sys/class/gpio/X/{direction,value}`. Is there a way to achieve this?

GPIO's trigger interrupts, which are polled using the `POLLPRI` flag. I need a way to re-create this behavior in full software, so I can test my code against different "physical input" automatically.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do this without external hardware connected to the gpios.

Have your test code alter the level of the gpios you want to test.

There are multiple ways.

- least intrusive, add an internal pull-up or pull-down to the gpio.
- write 0 or 1 to the gpio.
- generate PWM on the gpio to force constant level changes.

You haven't said anything which precludes this simple solution.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to do this w/o any hardware. Writing to the GPIO doesn't seem to work (permission denied, probably because the pins are in interrupt mode.

Comment: Use a library to access the gpios directly so bypassing the sys interface.  I've used the same technique to time Linux interrupt latency.  Set up a sysfs interrupt then use library software to toggle the gpio level.